# Why am I getting this error in my Bash script: “script.sh: line 8: [: too many arguments”?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

myIp=$(ip add sh | grep inet | grep -v -E 'docker|inet6|127'| awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1)

mySubnet=$(echo $myIp | cut -d'.' -f 1,2,3)

subnetBits=$(ip add sh | grep inet | grep -v -E 'docker|inet6|127' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f2)

#Check if not 24 bit

if [ $subnetBits -neq 24 ]; then

    echo "Subnet other than 24 bit detected - quitting now"

    exit 3
fi

for number in {1..254}; do

    if curl -s $mySubnet.$number:80 > /dev/null ; then

        echo "Found somebody listening on port 80 -- $mySubnet.$number"
    fi
done
```

Every time I try to run it, there is an error:

```
script.sh: line 8: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: Unquoted variables are a problem within `[...]` -- what exactly are the contents of the "subnetBits" variable?

Comment: Paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net for more help

Comment: Yes, the elders say [thou shalt quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). :)

Comment: Who are you calling "elder", Sonny? Get off of my lawn! ;)